# What are the benefits of Express over plain Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, express

So far, I see these benefits:

- Consistent Routing to modules
- Consistent Middleware interface (akin to a filter?)
- Handling for things like postdata, session management, static file serving, etc.

However, routing is very easily done with if statements and regex (that's what I do in Perl and Java already), and postdata and static file serving - well there's a module for that. So is it just that Express handles these things out of the box or is there a more significant feature I'm missing?

Maybe it's my point of view.. I'm writing my own webserver as part of a larger project, so maybe it's just that I'm replacing Express' more obvious features whereas many developers expect a webserver to be useable right out of the box?

On the other hand, I thought that people commonly made apps that listen on a TCP port, and then use ngix or some other HTTP proxy server for routing? Is Express supposed to replace this model?

Comment: I believe it's mainly the middleware interface (and the included middleware if you're using Express < 4 or Express >= 4 with the generator). It's a very nice way to consistently add features to a web server. If you are more interested in simpler middleware interfaces, you may find [Koa](http://koajs.com/) interesting.

Comment: Also, as far as I'm aware, most Node developers use their framework's HTTP server or Node's built in server.

Comment: 4 years later... do you have a further opinion @Bryan Field? My feeling is that all the benefits listed below, while they would save time to implement, also take time to figure out HOW to implement. My general feeling is that using Express, or other Node.js webserver frameworks is helpful as it's 'coding to a standard' that makes it easier for other developers to be able to work on off-the-bat.  But that there is very little value in terms of what they do, vs implementing the logic yourself

Comment: @Zach, I share your sentiment. I ended up rolling my own which was more tailored to what I wanted particularly. Better to build lean exactly what you need, than to bring in a bunch of overhead features beyond what you really wanted. You can always copy from work that was done before. For example the static file serving portion, was a port of a Java servlet that I liked. It doesn't amount to an enormous amount of code, but it takes time and then in the end it is designed with the exact options and features you really wanted all along.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read for yourself the API that [Express offers here](http://expressjs.com/api.html) and get a direct feel for what it adds to the base http server.

A partial list of features:

- All sorts of routing features including routing, separate handlers for `put`, `get`, `post`, etc..., wildcard handling, variables pulled automatically from URLs, etc...
- Sub routers
- Static file serving
- A framework that many popular template engines plugin to
- View caching
- Routing by case sensitivity or no case sensitivity
- A middleware framework which tons of third party NPM modules plug into
- eTag support
- All sorts of useful properties and methods to query info on the request
- All sorts of methods for constructing the response

Most folks building a web app would prefer to start with a web server and a framework and be able to use a wide variety of pre-built NPM modules that work with the framework rather than build all that stuff themselves.

`nginx` is sometimes used in concert with node.js (it has many features), but not usually as the main functionality that Express offers.

Comment: Thanks for the summary. This is helpful. They aught to include a similar summary on their website. Their API is too long unless you already know you're going to use it. I will endeavour to make my webserver compatible with Express framework, but that comes later, and I guess then I'll be reading the API. :)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of Node is so bad, you barely can use it.
Express instead shows clearly what they offer and how you can use it.
One big reason against Node.

Let's take the **Response Object** as an example:

Node Documentation:
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Express Documentation:
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

Comment: This isn't a relevant answer WRT what Express offers over plain Node.js. If this was relevant, then the Express team would have done better by providing 3rd party documentation rather than write a framework.

Comment: Obviously, `http.ServerResponse` is extended from `Stream` as pointed by the docs. It provides low-level configs like duplex(full, half) and I would say it provides more flexibility. But it's not the criteria that most web dev should be looking hence it's may(not) be good for them. It's just an opinion, please update your answer with relevant info like actual comparison.